# I want to make the array as unique using javscript map -- i am using react framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Database Contains duplicate values but I want to display unique data in dropdown in react.
I have tried using map but its not working

here is the code:

```
array.map(item => item.city)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
```

Comment: first filter out the unique into a new array then map through it.

Comment: There are tons of examples including here on stack overflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Comment: You can do as `self.indexOf(value, index + 1) === -1)` inside filter

Answer (score 1):

you can use [JS Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var array = [{city: 'Colombo'}, {city: 'Colombo'}, {city: 'Kandy'}, {city: 'Kandy'} ];

var uniqCities = [...new Set(array.map(e => e.city))];

console.log(uniqCities)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayWithDuplicates = [
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"NV"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "A7846", state:"CA"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"OR"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "10849", state:"CA"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "B7037", state:"WA"},
{"type":"LICENSE", "licenseNum": "12345", state:"NM"}];

function removeDuplicates(originalArray, prop) {
 var newArray = [];
 var lookupObject  = {};

 for(var i in originalArray) {
    lookupObject[originalArray[i][prop]] = originalArray[i];
 }

 for(i in lookupObject) {
     newArray.push(lookupObject[i]);
 }
  return newArray;
 }

 var uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(arrayWithDuplicates, "licenseNum");
 console.log("uniqueArray is: " + JSON.stringify(uniqueArray));
```

**ref : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38595329/14685679)**